# AjaxControlToolkit AsyncFileUpload - how to modify a label text value in UploadedComplete event

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to set a label text value after a file is uploaded to the server using a AsyncFileUpload component in AjaxControlToolkit. But it seams it is ineffective, although the file uploader is green after the upload, and the upload works.

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    string filename  = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload1.FileName);
    AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Uploads/") + filename); 
    sourceLabel.Text="saved to "+filename; //this has no effect. I assume this is because the event is Async, but how can I set the value of  sourceLabel?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AsyncFileUpload control uses hidden frame for file submitting so all updates of controls will be lost. Check this link and draw attention how the `uploadResult` label's text changed from  `AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete` method: [Ajax Control Toolkit source code](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a2a6dc6854e0#SampleWebSites/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx.cs)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12472235/2247978

.....................................................................................................

Add HiddenField control onto a form:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="UploadedPathHiddenField" />
```

Rewrite UploadComplete method as below:

```
protected void UploadComplete(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    var fileName = GeneratePrefixFileName() +  System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
    var relativePath = "~/Image/" + fileName;
    var filePath = Server.MapPath(relativePath);
    AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "filePath", "top.$get(\"" + UploadedPathHiddenField.ClientID + "\").value = '" + ResolveClientUrl(relativePath) + "';", true);
}
```

After that you can get path of saved image in showConfirmation method by :

```
var src = $get("<%= UploadedPathHiddenField.ClientID %>").value;
```

.....................................................................................................

```
protected void BtnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UploadMessage.Text = UploadedPathHiddenField.Value;
}
```